# Including Icon In Tkinter Window When Made In To An Executable

Tags: python, tkinter, markdown, executable

I'm using `Python 3.11` and I've made a Markdown reader program.

I've put an icon on a Tkinter window using the `iconbitmap` thing and when I run the Python file it all works well.

However, when I ran it as an executable (made using `cxfreeze`) and opened a markdown file it returned this error to me:

[image: Error]

It looks like it can't invoke the `iconbitmap` thing or it can't access `icon.ico`.

Here's my code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog as FileDialog
from tkhtmlview import HTMLLabel
import markdown
import sys
import os

dir_name = os.path.dirname(__file__)
dir_name = dir_name.replace("\\", "\\\\")
icon_dir = dir_name + "\\\\icon.ico"

def display_markdown(markdown_text):
    # Convert Markdown to HTML
    html_content = markdown.markdown(markdown_text)

    # Create the Tkinter window
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.iconbitmap(icon_dir)
    window.title("Markdown Reader")

    # Create an HTMLLabel to display the HTML content
    html_label = HTMLLabel(window, html=html_content)
    html_label.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

    # Run the Tkinter main loop
    window.mainloop()

def display_markdown_from_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        markdown_text = file.read()
    display_markdown(markdown_text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        display_markdown_from_file(sys.argv[1])
    else:
        file = FileDialog.askopenfile(mode="r", filetypes=[("Markdown Files", "*.md *.markdown")], title="Open Markdown File")
        if file is not None:
            content = file.read()
            display_markdown(content)
```

Comment: Have you added this icon file to your [setup](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/stable/setup_script.html)?

Comment: @8349697 I used the command line to freeze it (not the setup file) and yes, I did use the `--include-files` option for the icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem becomes clearer if we print the paths.**

```
...
import sys
import os

dir_name = os.path.dirname(__file__)
dir_name = dir_name.replace("\\", "\\\\")
icon_dir = dir_name + "\\\\icon.ico"

print(__file__)
print("dir_name", dir_name)
print("icon_dir", icon_dir)
...
```

### Outputs

*Note: The icon file (icon.ico) exists in the same directory as the Python script. I've simplified your program so that it only takes arguments and shows a GUI.*

Python file:

```
(env) F:\cxexe>test.py qwerty
F:\cxexe\test.py
dir_name F:\\cxexe
icon_dir F:\\cxexe\\icon.ico
```

Output for exe:

```
(env) F:\cxexe>cxfreeze -c test.py --target-dir dist --include-files icon.ico

(env) F:\cxexe>cd dist

(env) F:\cxexe\dist>test.exe qwerty
test.py
dir_name
icon_dir \\icon.ico
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
    return self.tk.call('wm', 'iconbitmap', self._w, bitmap)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "\\icon.ico" not defined
```

As we can see, the dir_name is now an empty string.

Backslashes become redundant in the file name.

```
>>> import os
>>> path = "test.py" # __file__
>>> os.path.split(path)
('', 'test.py')
>>> os.path.dirname(path)
''
>>> print(os.path.dirname(path) + "\\\\icon.ico")
\\icon.ico
```

[os.path.dirname](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname)

### Solution

---

Docs recommendation

```
...
import sys
import os


icon_file = "icon.ico"

def find_data_file(filename):
    if getattr(sys, "frozen", False):
        # The application is frozen
        datadir = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
    else:
        # The application is not frozen
        # Change this bit to match where you store your data files:
        datadir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    return os.path.join(datadir, filename)


def display_markdown(markdown_text):
    ...
    window.iconbitmap(find_data_file(icon_file))
    ...
```

[Docs](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#data-files)

[Another sample](https://github.com/marcelotduarte/cx_Freeze/tree/main/samples/tkinter)

---

Comment: That fixed the main part, but when I opened a file with the executable it returned the same error.

Comment: I don't get any errors unless I use backslashes and string concatenation to create the path. When running the updated executable, do you get the same error message (`bitmap '\\icon.ico' not defined`)?

Comment: The `os.path.join` fixed the part where when I normally start the executable and choose a markdown file. However, if I right click on a markdown file and choose the "open with" option and use the executable, it returns the same error (`bitmap 'icon.ico' is not defined`).

Comment: "def find_data_file" works fine for all the ways to run the executable. This is more suitable because this option relies on the sys.executable dirname.

Comment: The error in question is caused by an incorrect file path. The error you get when you right-click a file is related to the way the script gets the dirname. Indeed, I haven't tested the executable to work with the "open with" menu. I checked that the icon file name is correct. "os.path.join(dir_name, icon_file)" works when running the executable from the dist folder or if you double-click the executable. This option has limited use. "os.path.join(dir_name, icon_file)" does not work with "open with" on Windows.